# Nested If Loop in For loop does not work (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following loop which does not seem to work and I can't figure out why. Here are my variables first:

```
Joe_speed = 1.25  ##speed in m/s --> 4.5km/h = ((4.5*1000)/60)/60) = 1.25m/s
Jill_speed = 1.9
dog_speed = 5
total_distance = 5500 ## distance in meter between Joe and Jille when starting

JJtotal_speed = Joe_speed + Jill_speed
total_time = total_distance / JJtotal_speed ##time in seconds until meeting 
totaltime = int(total_time)
Jill_distance = total_time * Jill_speed
Joe_distance = total_time * Joe_speed
dog_start = total_distance


for i in range (1, (totaltime +1)*1000) : # multiplied by 1000 for milliseconds
    Jill_position = 0 + ((Jill_speed/1000) * i)
    Joe_position = total_distance - ((Joe_speed/1000) * i)
    dog_position = dog_start - ((dog_speed/1000) * i)
    if dog_position == Jill_position or dog_position == Joe_position:
        print("Hi")
    else:
        print("Ciao")
```

My if loop within the for loop does not seem to work however. Somehow neither "Hi" nor "Ciao" is being printed, i.e. the if loop is not happening? When I add print("...") at the end of the for loop (on the very left side on the bottom, this is being printed.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: What are the values for `totaltime`, `Jill_speed`, `Joe_speed`, and `dog_speed`?

Comment: Anyway, if your values are reasonable and they _should_ meet at some point, your problem is probably floating-point precision. You should almost never compare two floats with `==`. And `Jill_speed/1000)` and so on are likely to be floats (try `print(500/1000)` in your interactive interpreter).

Comment: @abarnert I thought the same! How can I compare two floats however? I tried to transform them to integers but that didn't work..Do you have any advice? And also should the loop then not return "Ciao"?

Comment: Read my answer; there's way too much to explain in a comment.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "if loop". You cannot loop using an `if`.

Comment: Your current code very nicely prints a lot of "Ciao" output lines.  There are no "Hi" lines, likely due to the aforementioned precision problems.  Solutions for that are well documented in many places.  The issue you raised here initially has been solved -- please select an answer to allow SO to properly retire the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that, if `totaltime` is 1746, then `(totaltime +1) //1000)` is 1. So you're looping over `range(1, 1)`, which means you're not looping at all.

Your second problem is that the scales are all way off, probably because you got one `*` and `/` mixed up somewhere. Everyone is moving so slowly that it'll take a ridiculous number of steps before Joe meets Jill.

But even if you ignore your `totaltime` and add a huge number of steps, neither of them ever meet the dog. They're not moving continuously, they're moving discretely. So Joe ends up crossing the dog's position between two steps.

Try adding a `print` call to see all three positions at each step, and you'll see all of these problems.

Even if you tweaked the numbers so that one of the people *should* meet the dog exactly at one of the steps, it might *still* fail. You're using floats. Most real numbers can't be represented exactly as floats, so the result of two different calculations that should both come out to 900.0 in ideal math could come out to just over 900 and just under 900 with float math. You could solve this by using `math.isclose` instead of `==`. But you need to solve the previous problem anyway, and doing that will solve this one.

So, after you solve the calculation for the first two problems, how can you solve the last two? You need to use `<=` and `>=` in appropriate ways instead of `==`. Which probably means keeping track of what the results were last time through the loop. If Joe < dog now, but Joe > dog a step ago, they've crossed each other. That's what you need to test for.

Comment: The poster's problem is that neither of the two possible print statements are executing.  Even if the dog never meets either of the characters you should still see one instance of `Ciao` for each execution of the `for` loop.

Comment: @LarryLustig He has multiple problems here, and he needs to fix _all_ of them. I explain why he's not looping at all at the top (although that may have gotten temporarily lost while I was re-editing after he gave us his numbers).

Comment: I don't think there's any particular reason to believe that the OP thinks that `Hi` will ever be printed.  So, I'm not convinced that the fact that it may never be printed is, in fact, a problem with the code.

Comment: @LarryLustig Read the OP's comments on the question about him suspecting floating-point comparison issues are his problem, I think that's a pretty solid reason to believe that he's expecting his code to do what it looks like it's supposed to do.

Comment: @abarnet My interpretation (for which I claim no infallibility at all) is that they believe they're looking for a reason that *neither* branch of the `if` statement executed.  They *may* be expecting to get `Hi` at the end of the loop, or they may not (at a guess, I bet they're *not* expecting to get the several tens of thousands of lines of output that the current code will produce).

Comment: You are both right! Adding the mulitplication solved the first problem I had with making the loop work at all, and now I'm trying to solve the problem to make the characters meet as abarnet also assumed and advised me on

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, the value of `totaltime` is such that the `for` loop is never executed.  You can check by adding a `print` statement as the first statement in the `for` loop.

**[Update]**

Based on your updated code, the answer above is correct.  Here's what's happening:

1. `totaltime` evaluates to 1746.
2. Your `range` upper limit is `totaltime / 1000`.  When dividing two integers in Python, the result is *integer*, created by *truncating* the resulting floating point number.  So `1746 / 1000` is `1` in Python.
3. Your range is therefore 1 to 1 and the `for` loop is never executed.

You can avoid the integer truncation issue by making one of the numbers in the expression a floating point number (that is, writing `1000.0` instead of `1000`, but that doesn't help because `range` needs integer arguments.

Comment: In this case, I think it's clear enough what's happening.  I can't be 100% certain because the OP did not supply the value of `totaltime`, but I'm confident enough I can help them out without getting too, too pedantic about it.

Comment: I think it's a matter of principle (not rewarding bad questions with answers), but alright.

Comment: The truncation isn't relevant here. `range(1, 1.746)` is illegal—`range` only takes int values. And even if it were legal, it wouldn't be any better than `range(1, 1)`.

Comment: Ah thanks you're totally right! The code should not contain a division by 1000 but a multiplication by 1000. I'll update my code in a sec.

Comment: @SVogels: does that fix the problem? You've updated the code with the multiplication but the question is still open, which is likely to confuse anyone who comes along and tries to answer it.